# Appium trigger test case on receiving push notification

Tags: java, automation, push-notification, appium

I am working on automating an app where the flow is, Once I get involved in the game, I will have to react to push notifications that are received in specific time intervals. I can currently achieve this by writing a wait. But I would like to know if there is an alternate way to do this. Is it possible to write any handler that would be called on receiving push notifications.So that I can trigger my automation code from there. Thanks in advance for your help.

I am looking for something similar to FCM, but mine is not a app code, its automation code, so not sure if it can be used here.